# How can I upload file (images) one by one in a sequential manner in the background in Ionic 3?

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I read [this](https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-images/) blog and found out about the `file Transfer plugin`. They used it to send a file(image) to the server. I want to send multiple file to a server one by one in a sequential order.

```js
public uploadImage() {
  // Destination URL
  var url = "http://yoururl/upload.php";
 
  // File for Upload
  var targetPath = this.pathForImage(this.lastImage);
 
  // File name only
  var filename = this.lastImage;
 
  var options = {
    fileKey: "file",
    fileName: filename,
    chunkedMode: false,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    params : {'fileName': filename}
  };
 
  const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
 
  this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Uploading...',
  });
  this.loading.present();
 
  // Use the FileTransfer to upload the image
  fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options).then(data => {
    this.loading.dismissAll()
    this.presentToast('Image succesful uploaded.');
  }, err => {
    this.loading.dismissAll()
    this.presentToast('Error while uploading file.');
  });
}
```

How can I **call this code in a sequential manner**, so that when one transfer finishes, another starts?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugin to transfer files. You can achieve this using XMLHttpRequest Native Browser API.

Below URL explains the various ways, we are transfer files to backend using XMLHTTPRequest API.

https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have an action like a button click that triggers the upload.

- Maintain a JSON array. Each individual item containing data that you need for
  the upload such as file name, file locations, destination url.
- On every click of the upload button, push another item into this array.
- Run a loop through the JSON array. For every item, call the upload
  function. All data that you need for the upload, already exists in
  the array item.
- Once the upload is successful, remove that item from
  the array.